# My question was labeled Off-Topic. Why?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I have a question about my Information Security Stack Exchange post: [How can I go about reporting a data breach in my private network without compromising my personal/private network data](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/270157/how-can-i-go-about-reporting-a-data-breach-in-my-private-network-without-comprom)

I don't know why my post was closed.

I understand that the first paragraph was not detailed but it did mention a few of my assets, which are my devices on my network and personal well-being (PII), which I need to protect.

My questions on the second paragraph, to my understanding, are clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

As I explained, this is a legal matter at best, or the question is unnecessary, at worst.

If the explanations are not helpful, then your question is not "clear enough".

Comment: None of your comments answered my questions. You misunderstood my questions because on one of your answers you misunderstood I wanted a random person to check my capture files for any anomalies. That was not the question I asked. The question asked is:  "Are there any laws that would protect my private data within those files?" These questions, to my understanding are clear enough. The best answer to my first question would be to get a lawyer. So, I will be asking this same question in the Law Community. To get a more appropriate answer. Thank you but no thanks.

Comment: My comment was: "If you think your devices are compromised, you need to ask the law enforcement in your area what your options are" For "does a law exist"? then Law.SE would be the best place. That's where you ask legal questions. I mentioned that too. Make sure you say what country you are in. I'm not sure why you're upset.

Comment: So, the question was legitimately closed as being "off-topic".

Comment: As you might already know I found out my network has been breached. I have reason to believe this has been going on for a while and I'm scared. I'm sorry I upset anyone. Have a great day to all.